# how to change title bar color in gnome flashback compiz Radiance theme in 14.04

Tags: gnome, compiz, themes, gtk

I'm using the gnome-flashback session (with compiz) in Ubuntu 14.04,
and I mostly like the Radiance theme.  However, the title bar only 
changes subtly between the focused window and the unfocused windows,
and I'd like to have the focused window's title bar a bright colour.

I have copied the Radiance theme directory to ~/.themes/my-Radiance,
and then selected this theme with gnome-tweak-tool.  Then changes I make 
show up, but I can't see what to change to affect the title bar colour.

I have also tried the radiance-colors package available via a ppa,
and I couldn't see any changes when I selected one of its themes.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

You need to edit metacity-1/metacity-theme-1.xml to change window decoration style.

https://wiki.gnome.org/Attic/GnomeArt/Tutorials/MetacityThemes - read this link to know more about metacity themes.

Comment: Please explain, how to do that (see [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer)).